# How to increase the hard disk space of thin provisioning virtual machine?

Tags: linux, vmware, suse, sles

Created thin provisioning VM (Suse Linux) with 100 GB hard disk. Now due to space requirements, I need to increase the size to 200GB. Can someone please tell me how to increase the space of the "/" directory?

```
Below is the output of the df -h command.

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs            12G  8.0K   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4.7G   18M  4.7G   1% /run
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        92G   53G   40G  57% /
/dev/sda1       511M  4.9M  507M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           2.4G   56K  2.4G   1% /run/user/467
tmpfs           2.4G   40K  2.4G   1% /run/user/465
tmpfs           2.4G   44K  2.4G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           2.4G   40K  2.4G   1% /run/user/0
```

```
Below is the output of the fdisk -l command.

GPT PMBR size mismatch (209715199 != 419430399) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sda: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 055ED88C-4E22-4F03-9C7F-4E4CCADBF54C

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  193429504 209715166  16285663  7.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda3    1050624 193429503 192378880 91.7G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I tried Fixing the partition and Correcting the GPT PMBR size mismatch using the below commands and rebooted. The system reboots fine.

```
Enter into the disk partition place: 
fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help):   m  
Command action
  ...
   l   list known partition types
   m   print this menu
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   w   write table to disk and exit
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

Command (m for help):   x

Expert command (m for help):   m
Command action
...
   f   fix partition order
   m   print this menu
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   r   return to main menu
   v   verify the partition table
   w   write table to disk and exit

Expert command (m for help):   f
Done.

Expert command (m for help):   w

The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

I turn off SWAP and delete the SWAP partition. I then deleted the "/" partition and created it again with the intended size of 190G.

```
Commands used:

swapoff -a

fdisk  /dev/sda
```

As "/" is still showing the older size I run the command xfs_growfs -d /. The size of the partition increases as intended. Now the issue is my system does not boot in normal mode(Just stays on 4 dots and lizard sign) whereas I can boot into recovery mode.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @NasirRiley `/dev/sda1` was EFI system. The second partition was `/dev/sda3` was `/` with type xfs. The third partition was `/dev/sda2` as a swap as shown in the above fdisk -l command output. I then fixed the partition and Corrected the GPT PMBR size mismatch using the commands in 3rd section above. Finally I deleted `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda2`. Recreated both the partitions again.

Comment: I see. To be clear, you deleted the partition `/dev/sda3` which was mounted at `/` and then recreated it. Is that correct? I'm just trying to get clarity on what actually happened.

Comment: @NasirRiley, Yes you are correct. I followed the steps on this link.

[Change_size_of_partition_using_fdisk_utility](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/extend-resize-primary-partition-non-lvm-linux/#Method_2_Change_size_of_partition_using_fdisk_utility)

Comment: Then that is why your system doesn't boot in normal mode aka the kernel release that was installed. The boot partition is still there but it can't boot into the filesystem loaded ad `/` because it contains nothing after you deleted it. Recreating it afterwards doesn't make any difference and neither does increasing the size of it. Do you have a backup?

Comment: Yes, I have a backup. But how can I extend/ change the size of the partition without deleting it? I followed the steps on this link. [Change_size_of_partition_using_fdisk_utility](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/extend-resize-primary-partition-non-lvm-linux/#Method_2_Change_size_of_partition_using_fdisk_utility).